# Some generated Icons appear larger than the normal icon

Tags: java, android, icons, package-managers

I'm currently making a list of all apps installed on my Device, but for some reason some Icons appear larger than the usual Icon.
How can I define the max size of the icons?

Here's the code I use to get the Icons

```
ImageView appIcon = holder.Icon;
            Drawable icon = null;
            try {

                icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(apps.get(position).name.toString());
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            appIcon.setImageDrawable(icon);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    PackageManager pm = context.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
    PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
    String title=pi.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
    Drawable icon== pi.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm))
```

or else , I assume that you are using a listview. set imageview width and height.

```
  <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/stats_icon"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

or

```
private static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
            if(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
                return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            }
        }

        if(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Single color bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel
        } else {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        }

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
```